# ECB Menu HTML/JavaScript Getting Indexed By Google

Tags: xslt-list-view-web-part, ecb-menu, seo

I have an XsltListViewWebPart on a publishing page. I am using custom XSL to style the view; I am not even using the ECB menu.

Why is Google indexing the ECB menu's HTML & JavaScript? When i search for my site with Google, I see the following:

[Google http://imageshack.us/a/img33/4882/6t4g.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img33/4882/6t4g.png)

In the WebPart's generated HTML, in the ECB menu's code block, I see the following `<div>`.

```
<div>javascript:commonShowModalDialog(&#39;{SiteUrl}/_layouts/itemexpiration.aspx?ID={ItemId}&amp;List={ListId}&#39;, &#39;center:1;dialogHeight:500px;dialogWidth:500px;resizable:yes;status:no;location:no;menubar:no;help:no&#39;, function GotoPageAfterClose(pageid){if(pageid == &#39;hold&#39;) {STSNavigate(unescape(decodeURI(&#39;{SiteUrl}&#39;))+&#39;/_layouts/hold.aspx?ID={ItemId}&amp;List={ListId}&#39;);  return false;} if(pageid == &#39;audit&#39;) {STSNavigate(unescape(decodeURI(&#39;{SiteUrl}&#39;))+&#39;/_layouts/Reporting.aspx?Category=Auditing&amp;backtype=item&amp;ID={ItemId}&amp;List={ListId}&#39;); return false;} if(pageid == &#39;config&#39;) {STSNavigate(unescape(decodeURI(&#39;{SiteUrl}&#39;))+&#39;/_layouts/expirationconfig.aspx?ID={ItemId}&amp;List={ListId}&#39;); return false;}}, null); return false;</div>
```

Now I am no SEO expert, but there is plenty of other relevant, semantic content both before & after this `<div>` that Google should be displaying rather than this nasty codeblock. (Why is this a `<div>` & not a `<script>` anyway?)

**Is there a way to remove the ECB menu entirely?** I am not using it at all (at least not on any publishing pages). If not, how can i ensure that it doesn't get indexed by search engines?

**Edit (10/1/2013)**: Lets approach this from a different angle. What horrible SEO mistakes could i have made that would have caused the ECB menu to get indexed over the other content? Most of the content preceeding the ECB menu is nothing but `<h1>`, `<p>`, & `<a>` tags wrapped in some `<div>` tags. There is some JavaScript animations, but everything is initially visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using the capabilities of the XsltListViewWebPart I'd suggest you use the Content Query Web Part instead which gives you more control about the rendered HTML.

Comment: That is a fair answer.

Comment: I am using the XsltListViewWebPart approach because i can deploy the XSL to the hive, use it in my list definitions, & deploy via a WSP. I believe using a ContentQueryWebPart will shift the XSL out of the WSP into the content level, which will make it harder for me to track & maintain.

Comment: All XSL files for the Content Query Web Part are stored centrally as well and can be provisioned using a WSP. By setting the desired permissions you can control who can modify them.